# react native link sharedLibrarie add lib to optional

Tags: react-native

react-native version
react-native-cli: 0.2.0
react-native: 0.41.2

after rnpm 1.9.0 version https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/releases/tag/v1.9.0

So when I public my lib, I can add lib in  sharedLibraries, just like that

```
"rnpm": {
    "ios": {
    "sharedLibraries": [
        "libz",
        "UserNotifications",
        "CoreTelephony",
        "Security",
        "CFNetwork",
        "CoreFoundation",
        "SystemConfiguration",
        "Foundation",
        "UIKit",
        "libresolv",
        "CoreGraphics"
    ]
    }
}
```

the problem was that the UserNotification.framework only available in iOS 10, so it could not be required, this framework status should be set to optional

Are there any configuration item to set this framework to optional after `react-native link`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate.h` do this -

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#endif
```

Have a look at this module for more information - https://github.com/GetuiLaboratory/react-native-getui/blob/master/example/document/iOS.md

Comment: It still crash in iOS 9

Comment: I guess you need to make more modifications. Check out that documentation.